# Need to grab data inbetween tilde character

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep

Can any one advise how to search on linux for some data between a tilde character. I need to get IP data however its been formed like the below.

```
Details:
20110906000418~118.221.246.17~DATA~DATA~DATA
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "20110906000418~118.221.246.17~DATA~DATA~DATA" | cut -d'~' -f2
```

This uses the `cut` command with the delimiter set to `~`. The `-f2` switch then outputs just the 2nd field.

If the text you give is in a file (called `filename`), try:

```
grep "[0-9]*~" filename | cut -d'~' -f2
```

Answer (score 1):

With **`cut`**:

```
 echo "20110906000418~118.221.246.17~DATA~DATA~DATA" | cut -d~ -f2
```

With **`awk`**:

```
 echo "20110906000418~118.221.246.17~DATA~DATA~DATA" 
       | awk -F~ '{ print $2 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

One more:

```
echo '20110906000418~118.221.246.17~DATA~DATA~DATA' | sed -r 's/[^~]*~([^~]+)~.*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
echo '20110906000418~118.221.246.17~DATA~DATA~DATA' | awk -F~ '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use bash

```
$ string="20110906000418~118.221.246.17~DATA~DATA~DATA"
$ echo ${string#*~}
118.221.246.17~DATA~DATA~DATA
$ string=${string#*~}
$ echo ${string%%~*}
118.221.246.17
```

Answer (score 0):

one more, using perl:

```
$ perl -F~ -lane 'print $F[1]' <<< '20110906000418~118.221.246.17~DATA~DATA~DATA'
118.221.246.17
```

bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS='~'

while read -a array;
do
    echo ${array[1]}
done < ip
```

If string is constant, the following parameter expansion performs substring extraction:

```
$ a=20110906000418~118.221.246.17~DATA~DATA~DATA
$ echo ${a:15:14}
118.221.246.17
```

or using regular expressions in bash:

```
$ echo $(expr "$a" : '[^~]*~\([^~]*\)~.*')
118.221.246.17
```

last one, again using pure bash methods:

```
$ tmp=${a#*~}
$ echo $tmp
118.221.246.17~DATA~DATA~DATA
$ echo ${tmp%%~*}
118.221.246.17
```